# Delete printer script with exclusions

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to use the script below to delete all printers with the exception of the printers in the collection. However only the first 2 printers in the collection are not deleted (printer1 + printer2). Somehow the others printers in collection are deleted, even though they should be excluded.

I've tried a few things, unfortunately my vbs script knowledge is pretty much zero to none.

```
Set oPrinters   = WshNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections

Dim aExclude()
Redim aExclude(5)
aExclude(0) = "\\PRINTSERVER\Printer1"
aExclude(1) = "\\PRINTSERVER\Printer2"
aExclude(2) = "\\PRINTSERVER\Printer3"
aExclude(3) = "\\PRINTSERVER\Printer4"
aExclude(4) = "\\PRINTSERVER\Printer5"
aExclude(5) = "\\PRINTSERVER\Printer6"

On Error Resume next
For I=0 to oPrinters.Count -1 step 2
  Set oPrinter = oPrinters.Item(i+1)
  For ii=0 to uBound(aExclude)
    If not oPrinter.Name = aExclude(ii) then
      bExclude = True
    End if
  Next
  Set oPrinter = nothing
  If bExclude = True then
    wshNetwork.RemovePrinterConnection oPrinters.Item(i+1), bForce, bUpdateProfile
  End if
  bExclude = False
Next
wscript.sleep 1000
```

Below are the installed printers

```
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set oPrinters = WshNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections

For i = 0 to oPrinters.Count - 1 Step 2
   WScript.Echo 
oPrinters.Item(i+1)
Next
```

```
    Output from the script above:
    \\PRINTSERVER\Printer1
    \\PRINTSERVER\Printer2
    \\PRINTSERVER\Printer3
    \\PRINTSERVER\Printer4
    \\PRINTSERVER\Printer5
    \\PRINTSERVER\Printer6
    \\PRINTSERVER2\Printer1
    \\PRINTSERVER2\Printer2
    \\PRINTSERVER2\Printer3
    \\PRINTSERVER2\Printer4
```

Comment: step 1 of any debugging is to remove the `On Error Resume Next` statement that could be hiding errors

Comment: Remove The `On Error Resume Next`